# App getting slow in IOS iPad (3rd generation) with Version: 9.3.5 (13G36)

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ipa, ios9.3

I created a Cross platform mobile application with Ionic1 framework with using angularJS.Recently I upgraded  ionic cli and cordova.So ,now the current configurations of the project is following:

global packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.5.0
Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1
Gulp CLI         : CLI version 3.9.1 Local version 3.9.1
Ionic CLI        : 3.5.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova : 1.4.1
@ionic/cli-plugin-gulp    : 1.0.2
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic1  : 2.0.1
Cordova Platforms         : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
Ionic Framework           : ionic1 1.3.0
```

System:

```
Node       : v6.9.5
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002
ios-deploy : 1.9.1
ios-sim    : 6.0.0
npm        : 3.10.10
```

I used a client side Socket.Io. in my application (version:1.4.5).Now the problem is that , App working properly in every device but in **iPad (3rd generation) Version: 9.3.5 (13G36)** , App is working  very slow and also all events (like tap , scroll) are slowly working.

**Can you please provide me the reason why the application getting slow  in IPad ?**

Comment: http://blog.ionic.io/cordova-ios-performance-improvements-drop-in-speed-with-wkwebview/

Comment: @Swapnil Patwa: Your solution has worked for IOS  but in android, App getting freeze. So there is any solution regarding  this issue for android.

Comment: Try https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview. But size of  APK will increase by ~15-20MB.